# How does the Python read the code? in what order in this case

Tags: python, inheritance

```
 class Animal:
    def set_health(self, health):
        print("Set in Animal")

class Carnivour(Animal):
    def set_health(self, health):
        super().set_health(health)
        print("Set in Canivour")

class Mammal(Animal):
    def set_health(self,health):
        super().set_health(health)
        print("Set in Mammal")

class Dog(Carnivour, Mammal):
    def set_health(self, health):
        super().set_health(health)

    print("Set in dog")


dog = Dog()
dog.set_health(10)
```

I know that Python reads this structure of code from left to right. But I can not understand how it changes the output when we swap the `Carnivour` with `Mammal` in `Dog()` class.

Could someone explain me in details how it reads the code that the output prints

```
Set in animal
Set in Mammal
Set in Carnivour
Set in dog
```

When we have the `Carnivour` first in `Dog()` class

Thanks for help and understanding

Comment: You did all your `print`s *after* the `super()` call in the method, so they print in LIFO order (the `print` from the last method invoked comes before all the others). Put the `print`s *first* and you'll see the actual invocation order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [method resolution order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) or MRO (Linked article is for Python 2.3 but, unlike most Python-2-centric articles this one is actually still relevant today). When you have multiple inheritance, Python linearizes the inheritance hierarchy to figure out where `super` should go. In your case, in the code you posted, the MRO is

```
Dog < Carnivour < Mammal < Animal
```

If you swap the order of inheritance in `Dog`, you get

```
Dog < Mammal < Carnivour < Animal
```

Since you make your "recursive" `super` call *before* printing, the `print` statements appear in the opposite order as the inheritance hierarchy.

You can read all about the details of the C3 linearization algorithm used for MRO in Python in the link above, but the basic idea is: Always follow the leftmost subclass first, unless doing so makes something nonsensical happen, where "something nonsensical" effectively means "a superclass appears before its subclass in the linearization".

Comment: Calling `Dog.mro()` will report the computed MRO of the class as a `list`, from first invoked to last.